# How can I draw temperature 3D plot?

Tags: plotting

I want to draw temperature 3D plot based on given data points {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},...}. Here z coordinate is temperature.Am going to Show the temperature z in corresponding {x,y} coordinate. In my example i used only 11 points. I tried like this.

```
list = {};
width = 50;
length = 30;
place = { {20, 4, 20}, {20, 10, 10}, {20, 15, 10}, {20, 19, 15}, {20, 
23, 5}, {20, 27, 60}, {40, 5, 50}, {40, 10, 30}, {40, 19, 
20}, {40, 27, 40}, {45, 10, 35}};
Table[AppendTo[list, Table[0, {x, width}]], {y, length}];
    Table[
                list = ReplacePart[list, {{y, x} -> place[[n, 3]]}],
                {n, Length[place]}, {y, place[[n, 2]] - 1,place[[n, 2]] + 1}, {x, place[[n, 1]] - 1, place[[n, 1]] + 1}
        ];
ListPlot3D[list, Mesh -> 10, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},RotationAction -> "Clip"]
```

Here i have given the data is x coordinate, y coordinate and z coordinate(temperature). Sub list {x,y,z} represent each point. In this manner, I want to create 1000 to 1500 points that are laid out in the plot with gap between each point shown clearly.

I have specified length and width of plot as 50 and 30 respectively. The problem am facing is i can't layout all(1000 to 1500) points in 50*30 dimension of `Plot`, even if i place all the points in 50*30 dimension plot the gap between each point is not shown clearly.

If i increase the dimension of list from 50 to 500 and 30 to 300 means 500*300, i will get the output but its really slow. Because 500*300 leads 150,000 data which makes the plot slow.

In this plot i have used `ReplacePart[]` function to replace 0 with given temperature and i have used table to span from previous point of current point to next point of current point  means -1 to 1(three points).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to show the data points separately, then `ListPlot3D` is probably not the way to go. How about using `ListPointPlot3D` with filling?

```
(* example data *)
place = {#1, #2, Sin[0.01 #1 #2]^2} & @@@ Tuples[Range[10], 2];

ListPointPlot3D[place, Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large],
  FillingStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

or just create your own `Graphics3D` directly:

```
Graphics3D[
 Cuboid[{#1 - 0.3, #2 - 0.3, 0}, {#1 + 0.3, #2 + 0.3, #3}] & @@@ 
  place, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Recycling [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21508/125) to a related question,

**Using `DiscretePlot2D` and `Interpolation`:**

```
dta1 = Array[{#1, #2, 0} &, {50, 30}];
replaceRl = (Join[#[[;; 2]], {0}] -> #) & /@ place;
dta2 = dta1 /. replaceRl;
intF = Interpolation[Join @@ dta2];
DiscretePlot3D[intF[i, j], {i, 1, 50}, {j, 1, 30}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 ExtentSize -> Scaled[.75],  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2},  ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

**Using `BubbleChart3D`:**

```
bchrtdata = Append[#, 1] & /@ (Join @@ dta2);
ceFunc[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}, {zmin_, zmax_}}, v_,  meta_] :=
  {Cuboid[{xmin, ymin, 0.}, {xmax, ymax, (zmax + zmin)/2}]};
BubbleChart3D[bchrtdata,  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#3] &), 
  ChartStyle -> Opacity[.9], ChartElementFunction -> ceFunc,
  BubbleSizes -> {0.01, .01}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]